# Make a usable custom radio button widget

Tags: flutter

How can I make the widget below usable?

```
Widget DryerRadio(String text, int index) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(
          () {
            dryer = index;
          },
        );
      },
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        side: BorderSide(
            color: (dryer == index) ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.white),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: (dryer == index) ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Above is a custom radio button widget that I found online and I want to make it usable. I tried creating a new Stateful Widget and came up with below:

```
class DetergentRadio extends StatefulWidget {
  DetergentRadio({super.key, required this.text, required this.index});
  String text;
  int index;

  @override
  State<DetergentRadio> createState() => _DetergentRadioState();
}

class _DetergentRadioState extends State<DetergentRadio> {
  int detergent = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          detergent = widget.index;
        });
      },
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        side: BorderSide(
            color:
                (detergent == widget.index) ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.white),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      ),
      child: Text(
        widget.text,
        style: TextStyle(
            color:
                (detergent == widget.index) ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that it's not working as a radio button. I tried it on my Detergent button first and
[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsj6b.png).
It is supposed to choose either one, not both.

Answer (score 0):

each instance must have a `value` & a group value that determines which one is `active` one

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import '../../config/index.dart';
import '../../utils/utils.dart';

class MyRadioButton<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T value, groupValue;
  final ValueChanged<T> onChanged;
  final Widget? child;

  const MyRadioButton(
      {Key? key,
        required this.value,
        required this.onChanged,
        required this.groupValue,
        this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyRadioButtonState createState() => _MyRadioButtonState();
}

class _MyRadioButtonState extends State<MyRadioButton> {
  late bool selected = widget.value == widget.groupValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const size = 21.0;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Utils.hideKeyboard();
        widget.onChanged(widget.value);
      },
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              curve: Curves.ease,
              width: size,
              height: size,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: selected ? kRed : Colors.transparent,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border:
                selected ? null : Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
              ),
            ),
            if (widget.child != null) ...[
              const SizedBox(width: kPadding / 2),
              Expanded(child: widget.child),
            ],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant MyRadioButton oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    setState(() => selected = widget.value == widget.groupValue);
  }
}
```

And this is a usage example;

```
MyRadioButton(
    value: 'female',
    onChanged: controller.gender,
    groupValue: controller.setGender,
    child: Text('female'.tr),
),
const SizedBox(height: kPadding / 2),
MyRadioButton(
    value: 'male',
    onChanged: controller.gender,
    groupValue: controller.setGender,
    child: Text('male'.tr),
),
```